# not able to loop .parent of a node in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I loop a parent of a node? I also am trying to use multiples of `$(this)`, which don't appear to be working.

```
$(window.xml).find('model').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text = selectedModel){
    $(this).parent().find('os').each(function() {
           osDropDowntxt += '<option value="' + 
                     $(this).text + '">' + $(this).text + 
                     '</option>';
    });
  }
));
```

Comment: `$(this).text` should be `$(this).text()`

Comment: Also, having the said XML would be nice!

Comment: http://supportishere.com/files/cab/cabs.xml

Comment: Im getting this now "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment".  I corrected the "text()" and the "))" at the end to "})".  Still not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where is the variable `osDropDowntxt` declared?

Comment: `function osDropDown() {
osDropDowntxt = '<form action=""><select id="osMenu" onchange="showLink(this)">';
selectedModel = $("#modelMenu").val();
    
$(window.xml).find('model').each(function() {
if ($(this).textContent == selectedModel {
    $(this).parent().find('os').each(function() {
    osDropDowntxt += '<option value="' + $(this).text + '">' + $(this).text + '</option>';
    });
}
});
osDropDowntxt += '</select></form>';
$("osDropDown").html(osDropDowntxt);
}`

Comment: http://supportishere.com/files/cab/index.html

Comment: I've found something, you have that line : `$("osDropDown").html(osDropDowntxt);` which should be `$("#osDropDown").html(osDropDowntxt);`

Comment: Thanks,  I fixed that code.  I'm still having issues, but that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working with the following code:

```
    for (i=0; i<newmodels.length; i++) {
    if (newmodels[i] == selectedModel)
    {
        $(window.xml).find('model:contains("'+newmodels[i]+'")').each(function() {
            $(this).parent().find('os').each(function() {
                availOS.push($(this).text());
            });
        });
    }
    }
```